# Application not running on Android device

Tags: android, installation, device

My application is running properly on emulator but not on device. Earlier I have run the same app on device many a times. I have turned USB- Debugging on my device, also set debuggable to true in manifest.

When I try to use command adb devices, it's showing me an empty list of devices.

Has anybody encountered same problem anytime?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: may i know whether you are trying to deploy or debug? what is the error you are getting when you deploy the apk file in your device? did your try this cmd adb install <location of apk file>

Comment: I'm trying to deploy my app on device. Whenever I'm running the application even if the device is connected, the app is run on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a list of things to try/check

-> Unknown Source to true

-> Debuggable requires USB Debugging

-> Non Mass Storage mode/USB connect to access the SD Card

-> unplug replug

-> reboot the phone (to be sure you can unplug the usb and remove the battery)

-> restart adb

Can you see an emulator ? can you launch your app on the emulator? can you launch a different project on the phone?

Comment: I am able to launch apps on emulator. No app is running on device now which was happening earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Keep ur phone connected with the system and then restart ur system.
I think it will work then.

Answer (score 0):

While connecting your device to desktop/laptop don't connect the device as a mass storage.